# Castaways rescued by a message in a bottle?

Tags: communication, nautical

Has there ever been a time when people were rescued by sending out a message in a bottle to drift across the sea?

- The "bottle" doesn't have to be an actual bottle.  It could be a box, a cask, a barrel, any kind of physical item bearing a message.
- It *does* have to drift across the sea, though.  There [was an incident](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/message-in-a-bottle-saves-80-migrants-adrift-off-costa-rica-494952.html) where some people off the shore of Costa Rica tied a message to a long line dragging behind a fishing boat -- that's not what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for a case where the message was carried by the sea.

Comment: If wikipedia doesn't know of it, most likely there's no known occurrance. I certianly couldn't find one. I was able to track down a link for the Costa Rican incident for you though.

Comment: @downvoter, please leave a comment explaining how you think this question can be improved, or why it's not a good question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not quite the traditional castaway rescue, but there was the case of the [Meermin slave mutiny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meermin_slave_mutiny), where the imprisoned slavers used a message in a bottle to alert shore forces to the slave mutiny, resulting in the defeat of the slaves and rescue of the slavers.

There's also the case of [Chunosuke Matsuyama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castaway#Chunosuke_Matsuyama), where a shipwrecked Japanese seaman sent a message in a bottle in 1784.  Unfortunately, it was not discovered until 1935; ironically in the village of his birth.

Other stories can be found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_in_a_bottle), although none tell of castaways actually rescued because of a message in a bottle.  It seems to be more a tradition of literature...